# Dataframe to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Hi I have such a dataframe and I want to make it a dictionary like below, I tried to_dict and to_json functions but I didn't get what I wanted. What should I do?

[image: DF]

```
{'http': '188.227.195.68:8080',
 'http': '41.207.251.194:8080',
 'http': '202.93.229.98:8080',
 'http': '46.254.247.59:3130',
 ...}
```

Sample Data

```
http_val    proxy
0   http    188.227.195.68:8080
1   http    41.207.251.194:8080
2   http    202.93.229.98:8080
3   http    46.254.247.59:3130
4   http    103.87.236.141:8080
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: is `http_val` always `http`?

Comment: A dictionary can contain a key only once, hence the above dictionary can *not* be constructed.

Comment: @user1558604 no it can be http or https

Comment: post your data please

Comment: @makis i edit my post

Comment: What should be keep in mind is that `dict` with repeated keys is syntax-wise legal in Python - it will just hold newest (rightmost) value for given key. For example doing `d = {'a':1,'a':2,'a':3}` and then `print(d)` results in `{'a': 3}`

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods to convert arrays to dict

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import csv

keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
values = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
list_of_tuples = list(zip(keys, values))
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns=['Key', 'Value'])
print(df.to_json(orient='records',lines='true'))
```

Comment: But it gets me ```{'index': [0, 1, 2], 'columns': ['key', 'value'], 'data': [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]}``` that

Comment: I fixed that. The code now outputs to a csv. Let me know if you want in dictionary

Comment: i need a dic, because i will use with dict :) thank you for answer btw

Comment: simplified it :)